# How to sum all Rdd samples in parallel with Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been racking my brain trying to do the following task (Just to keep simple).

First image you have an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.arange(0,12)
```

Then, I'd like to take random sample for that array. Assume you are interested to partition in 4 equal parts. Here I have my first problem. *How you can get 4 or more equal partitions using pyspark in a automated way?* (The brute force looks like this)

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(numbers)

rdd_sampled_1 = rdd.sample(False, 0.25)
rdd_sampled_2 = rdd.sample(False, 0.25)
rdd_sampled_3 = rdd.sample(False, 0.25)
rdd_sampled_4 = rdd.sample(False, 0.25)
```

The output should look like this:

```
rdd_sample_1 = [3 2 7]
rdd_sample_1 = [1 4 8]
rdd_sample_3 = [9 5 10]
rdd_sample_4 = [11 6 0]
```

Afterwards, I'd like to sum all this partials samples using map function. The should look like this:

```
collect_sample_1 = [12]
collect_sample_2 = [13]
collect_sample_3 = [24]
collect_sample_4 = [17]
```

**How you can do this using pyspark?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can randomly shuffle your numpy array, and pass the number of partitions as a parameter to `sc.parallelize()`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.shuffle(numbers)
rdd = sc.parallelize(numbers, 4)
```

Now we can use `mapPartitions()`, which needs a generator function; so to peak at the partitions we could do something like this:

```
def check_partitions(iterator): 
  parts = list(iterator)
  yield parts

rdd.mapPartitions(check_partitions).collect()
[[10, 7, 5], [3, 6, 8], [1, 0, 9], [2, 4, 11]]
```

To sum up each partition's contents, we can slightly modify this function:

```
def sum_partitions(iterator): 
  parts = np.array(list(iterator))
  yield np.sum(parts, 0)

rdd.mapPartitions(sum_partitions).collect()
[22, 17, 10, 17]
```